# SetVariable(var count, var count)

Tags: javascript

As the code below shows, I am appending a table with some table rows containing table data. The table data is getting appended with excel formula inside. How can I change the count variable inside td.class after it was appended in table upon click event or something similar.
I Want to update td.excel count attribute with onclick event

```
 .append("<td  class="
            excel " x:num x:fmla=\"=SUM(H" + count + " *I" + count + ")



     $("#example").on("click", "button", function() {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            count--;
                var i = 10;
                for (i = 10; i < count; i++) {
                    let div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("excel");
                    var attribute = div1.SetAttribute(count, count);

                }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Try improve it and provide a [mcve] so we can see what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Also, consult the docs for proper syntax and usage. E.g. `SetAttribute()`, it's spelled wrong when it comes casing and missing parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not clear. But what I've got from your question is that you want to dynamically append  to . But you end up with excel formula getting inside it.

So, according to me when you want to insert something dynamically then you should use `` these quotes instead of '' and "". eg :-

```
var i = 1;
.append(`<td class="hello${i}"></td>`)
```

Comment: Do not post an answer based on what you guess the question is. Wait until it been proper edited.

Comment: Also, when suggesting a solution, explain it as well, preferable with a link to a reliable resource, as how is users going to make sense of using (` `) compared to (' ') or (" ").